# How to implement scroll to specific position in angular using hyperlink

Tags: angular

Can anybody tell how to How to implement  scroll to specific position in angular using hyperlink .IN Html
We will implement like this

```
<a href="#google"></a>

<div id="google"></div>
```

Can anybody tell how can we implement in angular

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't the same work in angular?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code. I should be work.

app.component.html

```
<div class="nav">
   <span (click)="ScrollIntoView('#first')">first</span>
   <span (click)="ScrollIntoView('#second')">second</span>
   span (click)="ScrollIntoView('#third')">third</span>
</div>
<div id="first">
   <p>First</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
   <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div id="third">
   <p>Third</p>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
ScrollIntoView(elem: string) {
    console.log(elem);
    document.querySelector(elem).scrollIntoView({ 
        behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' 
    });
}
```

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrollintoview-sample